# how do I implement a transpose predicate the right way (Prolog)?

Tags: list, prolog

I am making a program that solves a puzzle. but I need to make a predicate that returns the transpose given a matrix(list of lists) and I can't use the predefined one. but whatever I do I can't get the predicate to work backwards without getting a stack limit exceeded, ex: `trans([[1,2],[3,4]],X).` returns `[[1,3],[2,4]]` but `trans(X,[[1,3],[2,4]]).` exceeds the stack limit.

here is the trans predicate:

```
trans(M,M1):-
    length(M,L),
    trans1(0,L,M,R).

trans1(N,N,_,[]).
trans1(I,N,M,M1):-
    I1 is I+1,
    column(M,I1,C),
    trans1(I1,N,M,M2).
```

and here is the column predicate that I used:

```
row([H|_],1,H):-!.
row([_|T],I,X) :-
    I1 is I-1,
    row(T,I1,X).

column([],_,[]).
column([H|T], I, [R|X]):-
   row(H, I, R), 
column(T,I,X).
```

any idea how I can use trans give the list if I give its transpose?

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, I wrote my own transpose/2, as a part of my [IL project](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL). Here it is:

```
% row/columns transposition
%
transpose_col_row([], []).
transpose_col_row([U], B) :- gen(U, B).
transpose_col_row([H|T], R) :- transpose_col_row(T, TC), splash(H, TC, R).

gen([H|T], [[H]|RT]) :- gen(T,RT).
gen([], []).

splash([], [], []).
splash([H|T], [R|K], [[H|R]|U]) :-
    splash(T,K,U).
```

Despite the code doesn't use anything complicated, it's not too easy to understand what it does, and, like your own, or SWI-Prolog library(clpfd) implementation, it is not 'reversible'.

Your code has many problems you need to solve (note: singletons warnings are errors, really), but assuming you can nail them down, and get a working trans(M,T), you could use a simple 'hack', swapping arguments after checking instantiation:

```
trans_rev(M,T) :- var(M) -> trans(T,M) ; trans(M,T).
```

Let's try with my own implementation, that is

```
transpose_col_row_rev(M,T) :-
    var(M) -> transpose_col_row(T,M) ; transpose_col_row(M,T).

?- transpose_col_row_rev([[1,2]],T).
T = [[1], [2]] 

?- transpose_col_row_rev(M,$T).
M = [[1, 2]],
T = [[1], [2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-assemble the predicate by looking at the publicly available, free (as in beer), open-source SWI-Prolog code. Why people don't do that more often is a mystery to me. It is very easy, but still more difficult than someone just dumping the working code on you I guess.

First, here is the (somewhat cryptic) [implementation of `transpose/2` in library(clpfd)](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/43721ddafe28828d82bd566a78ba0355f780b6a1/library/clp/clpfd.pl#L6833-L6899):

```
lists_transpose([], []).
lists_transpose([L|Ls], Ts) :-
        maplist(same_length(L), Ls),
        foldl(transpose_, L, Ts, [L|Ls], _).

transpose_(_, Fs, Lists0, Lists) :-
        maplist(list_first_rest, Lists0, Fs, Lists).

list_first_rest([L|Ls], L, Ls).
```

This uses a predicate `same_length/2`. It is defined in [library(lists)](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/43721ddafe28828d82bd566a78ba0355f780b6a1/library/lists.pl#L383-L394) and looks like this:

```
same_length([], []).
same_length([_|T1], [_|T2]) :-
    same_length(T1, T2).
```

Pretty straight-forward.

Then it uses `maplist` and `foldl`. Are there allowed or not? If not, you can rewrite `maplist(same_length(L), Ls)` as:

```
all_same_length([], L).
all_same_length([X|Xs], L) :-
    same_length(X, L),
    all_same_length(Xs, L).
```

Stupid code that shouldn't be written manually but well.

You can then replace `maplist(same_length(L), Ls)` with `all_same_length(Ls, L)`.

This leaves you with the `foldl(transpose_, L, Ts, [L|Ls], _)`. This is the "cryptic" bit; this qualification was maybe meant as a compliment to the person who wrote it.

Either way, a fold written like this that ignores the last argument (the result) can be re-written as a loop not too different from the maplist above. The `transpose_/4` used in the fold has a maplist in its definition, but I showed already how to do that.

Since this looks like homework I will let you figure it out on your own.

Cheat code: if you look far enough into the history of the library (all on github!) you might get super lucky and find a pre-foldl implementation of the same transpose.